# strtotime PHP for date numerical value + 1 week

Tags: php, strtotime

I have a day value of 1 through 7 where 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday.

I need to get a strtotime value of the appropriate day NEXT week.

For example:Today is Tuesday 13th November.

My day value is "2" so strtotime should return the appropriate value for Tuesday 20th November.
My day value is "1" so strtotime should return the appropriate value for Monday 19th November.
My day value is "5" so strtotime should return the appropriate value for Friday 23rd November.

I'm hoping this can be done with just a few built in PHP functions (strtotime(+1week+something))?
If not I will attempt to code some comparison checks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function dayNextWeek($num) {
  return date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 week +" . ($num - date('w'))  . "days"));
}
```

And to test:

```
foreach (range(1, 7) as $i) {
  echo $i . ' ' . dayNextWeek($i) . "\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 2012-11-19
2 2012-11-20
3 2012-11-21
4 2012-11-22
5 2012-11-23
6 2012-11-24
7 2012-11-25
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks! (knew it could be done with +1week + something!)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested extensively:

```
$givenDayNumber = 1;             // Your value here
$date = new DateTime();          // Today (reference point)
$currentDayOfWeek = date('N');   // This is 1 = Monday, see php date manual for more options
$diff = $givenDayNumber- $currentDayOfWeek; // Difference between given number and todays number
$date->modify('+ '.$diff.' day'); // Subtract difference
$date->modify('+ 1 week');        // Add a week
echo $date->format('d/m/Y');      // Output
```

Codepad here for fiddling: http://codepad.org/7SylbJOX

Answer (score 0):

```
function getNext($dow)
{
    $now = intval(date('N'));

    $toAdd = $dow - $now;
    if($toAdd<=0)
    {
        $toAdd += 7;
    }

    return date('r', strtotime('+'.$toAdd.'day'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, This should work for you.

```
<?php
$array = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday');
$your_value = 2;
$str = 'next ' . $array[$your_value -1];
echo date('D d M Y', strtotime($str));

?>
```

http://codepad.org/OIrzRxpl

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $day_nxt_week = date('N', strtotime(date('Ymd') . '+1 week'));
 print_r($day_nxt_week);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.org/tWSsT4aD)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This just returns "2" though and not the strtotime value based on the offset? Thanks!